# Is it possible to install php gearman extension on wamp or xampp ( windows )

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, gearman

Is it possible to install php gearman extension on wamp or xampp in windows? I'm running after it for many days. No good news.

Comment: I dont see why not, but as the pecl source has not been maintained since 2013 you may need to do a bit more research

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and how you failed so that we can help you with a specific issue. As currently written, this is a too broad question to answer (unless you're looking for just "yes")

Comment: I've installed libevent, gearman via cygwin as per instructions on : https://gist.github.com/mnapoli/5270256

Please check: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a0Ep6ubUAoMhHm7ARaMtV6Q627S5YCw4/view?usp=sharing

Can you please tell me what i'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gearman can be installed on Windows through cygwin.

- https://www.cygwin.com/
- https://gist.github.com/mnapoli/5270256

Good luck, you'll tell me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Gearman successfully installed as per your instructions. But how can i use Gearman with XAMPP or WAMP.. Do i have to edit something on php.ini file ?

Comment: I found a Gearman wrapper for Windows: mhlavac/gearman on GitHub.

Comment: Can you please give me a step-by-step instructions to use this wrapper ? I'm trying to learn these things for 3-4 days.. But no use.. Please help me.. I'm totally a beginner on gearman and composer.. etc..